# Java String format decimals only

Tags: java, string, format, string-formatting, string.format

Is there a way to format a double using `String.format()` to only get the decimals?

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", 1.23456d));
```

As expected, the above line returns '1.23', but in this case I'm only interested in '.23'. 
Aditionally I'm not interested in anything before the decimal sign, also no leading 0.

Is this possible with `String.format()` or do I need to use `DecimalFormat`?

Cheers

Comment: if the number comes from a primitive datatype like float you could do
(myFloat - (int)myFloat)

Comment: You're correct. But this would leave the leading 0 --> 0.23 I'd also like to get rid of the leading 0 with one String.format expression if possible ;). Will update the text above in a sec...

Comment: @darksaga Then unfortunately no. In format formula after dot you can set precision, but before dot you set minimal width of output data which cant be set to zero for floats (negative value will only adjust output to left side, positive to right side).

Comment: What about turning it into a string and using split("\\.") to get the decimal part?

Comment: @DeH Currently I'm using the following expression: String str = String.format("%.2f", 1.23456d);str = str.substring(str.length()-3); I thought that I could get rid of the substring if there was a possiblility to format it with String.format directly, to make my code a little more efficent ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can post-process the output of *String.format* :

```
String.format("%.2f", 1.23456d).replaceFirst("^[^.//]+", "")
```

Comment: That's what I do at the moment, see my comment above (@DeH). I think the replaceFirst() code using a regexp will be slower than the substring code I'm using at the moment, though. I was trying to get rid of unnecessary string operations ;)...